# SQL If 'x' then include all possible values

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a query in Oracle SQL and am trying to add a prompt that limits results when checked and if left unchecked then the criteria is ignored (or returns all possible results). Specifically, the query returns all employees worldwide. The checkbox (possible values are Y or N) is to limit results to North America only (using the field 'Country' and the values 'USA' and 'CAN'). There are a number of other countries and instead of listing them all out I would like to just say "include all values" or "ignore the limiting criteria".

Essentially I'm trying to do this:
If the box is checked then return only employees whose value in the country field is USA or CAN.
If the box is unchecked then return all employees regardless of the value in the country field.

I have tried a case statement

```
[COUNTRY] = CASE WHEN (PROMPT = 'Y') THEN ('USA' OR 'CAN')
WHEN (PROMPT = 'N') THEN (LIKE '%') END
```

but I am getting error messages for
1) multiple values after THEN (using "'USA' or 'CAN'") and 
2) how to code for "any value" in the PROMPT=N section.

I have tried many permutations of OR, IN, ANY for the multiple THEN values to no avail. And I have researched and tried permutations of wildcard values % and _ for the 'any value' section. I have also tried writing this as an IF statement but that didn't work either.

I am a sql novice and any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to to this would be with an OR statement.  There's no need for any further test when the value of the prompt indicates "give me everything".

```
where  (
              (:PROMPT = 'Y' and COUNTRY IN ('USA', 'CAN') )
          or  (:PROMPT = 'N')
       )
```

Note: the syntax for denoting a parameter will vary depending on how you call the query.  I've used `:PROMPT` above but change it to whatever you need.

Comment: Perfect! And elegant. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways of doing it is like this:

```
WHERE 1 = CASE WHEN (PROMPT = 'Y') THEN 
   CASE [COUNTRY] IN ('USA','CAN') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
WHEN (PROMPT = 'N') THEN 1
ELSE 0 END
```